# spring security xml explanation

Tags: spring, spring-security, aop

I am a newbie to spring security. I want to understand what do following lines do to my web application

```
<security:http>
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
  <security:form-login />
  <security:logout />
</security:http>
```

As far as I understand

1. intercept-url means when request to any resource having location matching the pattern specified in pattern property is received, show the form-login.
2. form-login means give me default form login
3. logout means give me default form logout

Please correct above points if they are wrong/inadequate. Also, can someone explain what does `access="ROLE_USER"` do?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. For every `intercept-url` Spring Security will check if there is a logged user and if he/she has the needed role to access the url. In your case you match all requests. Notice that if you have multiple `intercept-url` they are evaluated in the order they are written in the config(if you put a wider `intercept-url` before some narrower one the later will not be evaluated).

2,3. You got it right.

To understand the access attribute, you have to know about authentication manager and provider. For example you can have:

```
    <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="myuser" password="mypass" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            <user name="myadmin" password="mypass" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        </user-service>
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

(there other authentication-providers, for JDBC, LDAP...)
If you add another intercept-url:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
```

it will be accessible by myadmin, but not by myuser.

Answer (score 0):

only user with ROLE_USER in their granted authorites can access the resource.